# When using readline() function, why is it necassary to pass NULL as its argument?

Tags: c, xcode, null, char, readline

In C programming why do you pass NULL as a argument when using the readline() function?
Is there any other way to store the name beside using const char?

```
#import <readline/readline.h>
#import <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("Who is cool? ");
    const char *name = readline(NULL);
    printf("%s is cool!\n\n",name);

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: when using this code (in Xcode) I noticed the characters I typed was echoed back. 
SO what I see from the console was actually like so:

> > who is cool? MMiikkeeyy
> >
> > Mikey is cool!

Is there an explanation to why this happens?

Comment: Would not you like to read the function description if you are using it in your code?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This is a code from a book I'm reading, and it doesn't have a function description.

Comment: I think that there is an explanation of the function in this book. Otherewise you should not read this book if you do not understand what is written in the book and should start to read a more simple book.

Comment: There isn't a lot of information about this function because it's not a standard function. I had to add the library libreadline.dylib before I could use readline() in Xcode. That's why I want more information from this community, from people who know better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `readline` function is [a GNU thing](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html), allowing for user input with all the editing power found in various shells.

The argument is simply a prompt to issue before asking for input, so your code is equivalent to (in C code since my Mac is not handy):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    const char *name = readline ("Who is cool? "); // Don't need separate printf.
    printf ("%s is cool!\n\n", name);

    return 0;
}
```

Further details on how to use it can be found [here](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC23), one of the pages referenced by the link in the first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You Pass  NULL as an argument when using the readline() function because the compiler should know in advance that there is no line written there before any execution. Hence avoiding this type of error we use NULL .
          And You Can store your characters using pointers and arrays in c.